# GitHub API create file not creating

Tags: javascript, token, node-modules, github-pages, github-api

I was trying to create a website where I could put in some data, and it would send GitHub API a POST request to create a file with the specified data. I am using GitHub Pages to host.

I created a test script that should create a file once the page loads, and it worked originally, but as I came back to test it again 2 hours later, it didn't create a file. What am I doing wrong? Note: I'm using personal tokens for this, is that an issue?

Here's my code:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Dev portal</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  Hello world
  <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**script.js:**

```
import { Octokit } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/@octokit/rest";
  const octokit = new Octokit({
  auth: 'iputmytokenhere'
})

await octokit.request('PUT /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}', {
  owner: 'Skoolgq',
  repo: 'skoolgq.github.io',
  path: 'test2.txt',
  message: 'Test commits for JSON API',
  committer: {
    name: 'Skool Developers',
    email: 'help@skool.gq'
  },
  content: 'bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM='
})
```

Comment: From [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-or-update-file-contents)... _"`sha` - **Required if you are updating a file**. The blob SHA of the file being replaced."_

Comment: @Phil But I'm not updating a file, i'm creating one.

Comment: Ah, I see. I used the filename of a file that already exists. Oops! Let me try it with a different file name

Comment: Issue solved. I can't believe I was creating a post over a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using an existing filename. Silly me!